# Let's design a Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey theme for the site!

Tags: discussion

Here is the **reason** we might want to do this,

We **could graduate tomorrow and still not get a theme in the [next two years.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles)**

If you don't believe me, check the list of the [latest sites to have graduated](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched). As you can see of the last 11, only two have themes.

--

**However, it is possible with [the use of some scripting](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7955) to design a theme ahead of time**. That way we can bounce ideas and make it look pretty ahead of time.

So far I have a **proof of concept** script up and have made three small changes, adding a border to the tags, changing the color of the questions and changing the **upvote icon on upvoted post to a green tree** icon that I found for free.

[image]

The script is [here](https://github.com/CharlieBrumbaugh/GreatOutdoorsTheme) in a Github repository, to give it a try in Chrome you will need to install [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) and then copy and paste this [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CharlieBrumbaugh/GreatOutdoorsTheme/master/greatoutdoors.js) into the Create a new script option. (Upvoting now feels like planting trees)

**Things we can change**

- Icons for upvoting (I like the green tree)
- Icons after downvoting (maybe thunderclouds/ tree on fire)
- Special badge icons (maybe carabiners?)
- Background color of accepted answers
- Favorite icon (maybe  a sun icon?)
- Change the tag background color
- Change the font colors
- Create a header image
- Probably more things I haven't thought of.

**What people could help with**

- Creating the icons
- Coming up with ideas for the color scheme
- Testing it out once we have more of it written
- Actually writing the script.

Thinks to note.

- This won't change anything for anyone who doesn't have the script running.
- Let's host the icons with imgur just like all of the other images.
- If you want to contribute to the Github repo, I believe that I just need your Github username to add you. Let's do the feature request branch style, with all changes to master being done with pull requests.
- This is my first Tampermonkey script ever, I probably messed something up somewhere.

Comment: I would still say it's ok to not have a theme of our own after graduating. I belong to @ab2 category of not liking fancy stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to be a wet blanket, but I don't like fancy stuff, because fancy stuff gets boooring very quickly.  Uparrow and Downarrow are fine with me.

Answer (score 3):

How about we work on getting more questions per day and increasing our answer ratio so we can get out of beta and get our site launched? Then we can have a genuine site theme instead of trying to come up with a work-around and pretend we're launched.

If we got 10 people to commit to posting one question per day (even if they are bad questions) then we might at least fake our way out of beta eventually, and get a site design.

Comment: How many questions per day do we need to get out of beta, and what kind of commitment would we need from how many people for how long?   I can't do one Q per day, but I probably could do one Q per week.

Comment: @ab2 10 question per day. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3659/the-great-outdoors

Comment: ShemSeger, Is the last part of this answer kind of tongue-in-cheek, or like a joke on purpose? I'm thinking about your other post about [composing quality answers](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/composing-quality-answers), and this one suggests asking questions with bad answers just to fake our way out of beta. This is facetious right?  (Not my downvote by the way, I'm just curious about what you meant!)

Comment: @sue, I meant to say 'questions'. There are other SE sites that don't get many more questions than we do, but they're still launched. Those other sites also [close a lot of their questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289797/2016-a-year-in-closing).

Comment: Oh, 'questions' makes much more sense!!! That's a fascinating graph. Is there a way to update it, since it's from 2016, or at least for our site?

Comment: I'm going to try posting more questions. I've been a bit inactive of late. I'll keep posting as and when I can. I usually post only those things for which I have no answer for. However, I do see that many questions here are self answered as well. If possible I'll do that too (although I doubt that).

Answer (score 1):

Limiting my response to one suggestion

> Special badge icons (maybe carabiners?)

If you open the door to manufactured items like 'carabiners' then you set a foundation for others like knives and guns that will lead to politically charged debates.

**IF** customizations are used, they should stay more Earth based as opposed to Human made.